# How to dynamically resize an Excel userform in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, resize, userform

In Excel 2019, I want to get people's names from filenames such as this: `Summer Lovin' - John Travolta & Olivia Newton-John` or this: `Eddie Rabbitt sang a duet with Crystal Gayle in 1982`.

I have created a userform dynamically so I can select the valid names and add them to a list on a spreadsheet.

[image: userform example]

However, I have not found a working solution to change the size of the userform to fit the label and checkboxes.

Any idea of what I need to do? I'm open to all suggestions.

```
Option Explicit
Sub SplitstrFNForNames()

    Dim strFN, substr, substr1, substr2 As String
    Dim i, n                            As Integer
    Dim MyUserForm                      As VBComponent
    Dim chkBox                          As MSForms.CheckBox
    Dim Label1                          As MSForms.Label

    ThisWorkbook.Save

    If Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "B") = "" Then
        strFN = "Summer Lovin' – John Travolta & Olivia Newton-John"
    Else
        strFN = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "B")
    End If

'    Check whether the userform form exists
    For n = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Count
        If ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(n).Name = "MsgboxFNSplit" Then
            ShowMsgbox
            Exit Sub
        Else
        End If
    Next n

'    Make a userform
    Set MyUserForm = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_MSForm)
    With MyUserForm
        On Error Resume Next
        .Name = "MsgboxFNSplit"
        .Properties("Caption") = "Get performers names from filename"
    End With

    Set Label1 = MyUserForm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.label.1", "Label_1", True)
    With Label1
        .Caption = "Check names to be added to performers list"
        .Left = 5
        .Top = 5
        .Width = 144
    End With

'    Add checkboxes to userform
    i = 1

    Do
        substr1 = Left(strFN, InStr(1, strFN, " ") - 1)
        strFN = Replace(strFN, substr1 & " ", "")

        If InStr(1, strFN, " ") = 0 Then
            substr2 = strFN
        Else
            substr2 = Left(strFN, InStr(1, strFN, " ") - 1)
        End If

        substr = substr1 & " " & substr2

        Set chkBox = MyUserForm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "CheckBox_" & i, True)
        chkBox.Caption = substr
        chkBox.Left = 5
        chkBox.Top = Label1.Height + 5 + ((i - 1) * 20)
        i = i + 1

    Loop Until InStr(1, strFN, " ") = 0

    ' Calculate height & width of userform based on sizes of labels and checkboxes
    Dim h, w
    Dim c As Control

    h = 0: w = 0
    For Each c In MyUserForm.Controls
        If c.Visible Then
            If c.Top + c.Height > h Then h = c.Top + c.Height
            If c.Left + c.Width > w Then w = c.Left + c.Width
        End If
    Next c

    If h > 0 And w > 0 Then ' <<< This is not working
        With MyUserForm
            .Width = w + 40
            .Height = h + 40
        End With
    End If

    ShowMsgbox

'   Remove userform
    With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
        .VBComponents.Remove .VBComponents("MsgboxFNSplit")
    End With

End Sub

Sub ShowMsgbox()
    MsgboxFNSplit.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: always use `Option Explicit`. If you do you will see that `Dim h, w` is not declaring the variables to a specific type, but the default type `Variant`, which is a catch all type. And because `h,w` are variant, Excel cannot do math on it, so `h>0` fails, for example. Declare them both as `Long`. `Dim h as Long, w as Long`.

Comment: @Scott Holtzman: You are right with the statement that h and w shouldn't be `Variant`. However, VBA can do math with them - with the initialization with `0`, they get numbers. And to be precise, they should be declared as `Double`, not as `Long`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have (at least) two errors in your code, but you don't see them as you unfortunately hide them with the evil `On Error Resume Next` statement.

(1) To access the controls of the form at design time, you need to access them via the `Designer`-object:

```
For Each c In MyUserForm.Designer.Controls
```

(2) To set the Width and Height of the form, use `.Properties`:

```
    With MyUserForm
        .Properties("Width") = w + 40
        .Properties("Height") = h + 40
    End With
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly. I removed the ```On Error Resume Next``` statement.